# How to set maximum length of wordpress the_title?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, maxlength

I want to set the maximum length of the title in WordPress advance custom field.

I use like this but it was not working :

```
<p style="position:relative;top:-30px;">    
    <?php
     $post_object_th = get_field('therapeutic_class');
     if( $post_object_th ): 
       $post = $post_object_th;
       setup_postdata( $post ); 
       $g_name = get_the_title();               
     endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
    <?php echo wp_trim_words( $g_name, 1 ); ?>
 </p>
```

Comment: You can try this once https://firstsiteguide.com/wordpress-titles/

Comment: But I only change this title not others. If I applied this it will be changed other titles?

Comment: You want to change any specific title.

Comment: yes. I want to change the specific title length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer Just use this php function `substr()`:

```
<?php echo substr($g_name,0,10).'...';?>
```